# Evaluation error: std::bad_alloc. :Error in extracting neighbors of geometric points from specified multi-ring buffers in R

Tags: r, buffer, r-sf, bad-alloc

I am executing the following code from https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/357997/creating-multi-ring-buffers-around-points-in-a-single-layer-and-for-each-point-s.

```
library(sf) 

library(dplyr)

library(ggplot2)
library(stringr) 
library(rgdal) 
library(lwgeom) 
library(sp)
#library (bigmemory)
#library (biganalytics)
```

The `Pointsdata` has the following format:

```
Pointsdata<- data.frame(ID = paste0("ID_", 1:20), lon = runif(20, -20, 20), 
       lat = runif(20, -20, 20), pop_size = runif(10, 0, 2000))
```

```
> head(Pointsdata)
    ID        lon        lat  pop_size
1 ID_1 -10.051100  18.441917  675.3872
2 ID_2   5.394999   4.148627 1472.2674
3 ID_3   1.306370  15.794475  137.6444
4 ID_4   5.910318  -6.438676 1380.2332
5 ID_5   9.355191 -10.118736  513.3624
6 ID_6  -4.804669  -7.762536  212.9331
```

```
#load raw data
Mydata <- read.csv("Pointsdata.csv") # My actual data


#Transform and project to required UTM
projdata <- st_as_sf(Mydata,coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326) %>% st_transform(26913)



bufferR <- c(402.336, 1609.34, 3218.69, 4828.03, 6437.38) # sequence of radii in miles??

#Create data of neighboring wells per buffer

dataout <- do.call("rbind", lapply(1:length(bufferR), function(y) {
    bfr <- projdata %>% st_buffer(bufferR[y]) ## create Buffer
    ## minus the next smaller buffer
    if(y>1) {
      inters <- suppressWarnings(st_difference(bfr, projdata %>% st_buffer(bufferR[y-1])))    
      bfr <- inters[which(inters$ID == inters$ID.1),]
    }

    # get ids that intersect with buffer

    inters <- bfr %>% st_intersects(projdata) 


    do.call("rbind", lapply(which(sapply(inters, length)>0), 
         function(z) data.frame(orig = projdata[z,]$ID, radius = bufferR[y],
                incl = projdata[unlist(inters[z]),]$ID, 
                afpump_mtchd = projdata[unlist(inters[z]),]$afpump)))
}))


write.csv(dataout,'data.csv')
```

Everything runs fine when I run it on round a **1000** location points. But beyond a 1000 points, R throws out the following error:

`Error in CPL_geos_op2(op, st_geometry(x), st_geometry(y)) : Evaluation error: std::bad_alloc.`

By "experimenting" with different sizes of my data, it appears this as an issue of inadequate memory which is quite surprising because I think my 16GB RAM should be able to take care of this analysis.

After several days of googling around this problem and reading around to understand without success how quite similar problems were resolved on other platforms, I decided to raise it here, hoping I could get help on it.

My session info is :

```
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] lwgeom_0.2-1  rgdal_1.4-8   stringr_1.4.0 ggplot2_3.3.0 dplyr_0.8.5  
[6] raster_3.0-12 sp_1.4-0      sf_0.9-0     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.4         pillar_1.4.3       compiler_3.6.3     class_7.3-15      
 [5] tools_3.6.3        lifecycle_0.2.0    tibble_3.0.0       gtable_0.3.0      
 [9] lattice_0.20-38    pkgconfig_2.0.3    rlang_0.4.5        DBI_1.0.0         
[13] cli_2.0.2          e1071_1.7-3        withr_2.1.2        vctrs_0.2.4       
[17] classInt_0.4-2     grid_3.6.3         tidyselect_0.2.5   glue_1.3.2        
[21] R6_2.4.1           fansi_0.4.1        purrr_0.3.3        magrittr_1.5      
[25] scales_1.0.0       codetools_0.2-16   ellipsis_0.3.0     units_0.6-6       
[29] assertthat_0.2.1   colorspace_1.4-1   KernSmooth_2.23-16 stringi_1.4.6     
[33] munsell_0.5.0      crayon_1.3.4      
>
```

My memory limit also is:

```
> memory.limit()
[1] 16257
```

Can someone help me with any ideas on how to resolve this problem?